# Why child process behaviour is so strange?

Tags: c++, c, linux, process

I wrote a code snipped which creates child processes.

Code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
void B();
void C();
void D();
void E();
int main (){
    int status;
    printf("Name: %s, PID: %d, PPID: %d.\n", "A", getpid(), getppid());
    if (fork() == 0) {
        B();
    }
    if (fork() == 0) {
        C();
    }
    wait(&status);  
}
void B(){
    //B process
    int status;
    printf("Name: %s, PID: %d, PPID: %d.\n", "B", getpid(), getppid());
    if (fork() == 0) {
        E();
    }
    if (fork() == 0) {
        D();
    }
    wait(&status);
}
void C(){
    //C process
    printf("Name: %s, PID: %d, PPID: %d.\n", "C", getpid(), getppid());
}
void E(){
    //E process
    printf("Name: %s, PID: %d, PPID: %d.\n", "E", getpid(), getppid());
}
void D(){
    //D process
    printf("Name: %s, PID: %d, PPID: %d.\n", "D", getpid(), getppid());
}
```

The problem is I got output which I didn't expect at all.
Logs:

```
Name: C, PID: 4571, PPID: 4570.
Name: D, PID: 4572, PPID: 4569.
Name: C, PID: 4573, PPID: 4572.
Name: C, PID: 4574, PPID: 4567.
Name: C, PID: 4575, PPID: 4569.
------------------------------
Name: A, PID: 4576, PPID: 4147.
Name: B, PID: 4577, PPID: 4576.
Name: C, PID: 4578, PPID: 4576.
Name: D, PID: 4580, PPID: 4577.
Name: E, PID: 4579, PPID: 4577.
------------------------------
Name: D, PID: 4582, PPID: 4579.
Name: C, PID: 4581, PPID: 4580.
Name: C, PID: 4583, PPID: 4582.
Name: C, PID: 4584, PPID: 4577.
Name: C, PID: 4585, PPID: 4579.
```

each launch separated by -------------------------

Why does C process runs multiple times and each time changes his PPID?
Why I don't see message from A process (parent)?
Waiting for your answers and link to resources!

Comment: OT: The code misses the prototype for `wait()`.

Comment: "*each launch separated by -------------------------*" I doubt this.

Comment: The log lines from the 2nd and 3rd block are from the one same run.

Comment: omg, isn't wait a library function? (sorry I am absolutely new in c)

Comment: nothing changes from this at all.

Comment: "OT" = "Off Topic" and should have indicated this most probably does not help.

Comment: Adding to my 2nd comment: You most likely misinterpret the outyou get from running the pogram several times in a row. Run it from the console hitting the enter-key a few times between the runs and you see what I mean.

Comment: I got this https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxqHIsjAh-jWOFM4a1ppU0dCd00&authuser=0

Comment: So everything is around. No missing A for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the side effects of the fact that `stdout` is buffered. I modified your program to:

1. Flush `stdout` after each call to `printf`.
2. Added a function to print an indent based on an indent level. The indent level of the main process is `0`. The indent of level of the children of the main process is `1`, etc.

I get the following output:

```
Name: A, PID: 694812, PPID: 23788.
   Name: B, PID: 695816, PPID: 694812.
   Name: C, PID: 693016, PPID: 694812.
      Name: E, PID: 691184, PPID: 695816.
      Name: D, PID: 695896, PPID: 695816.
         Name: D, PID: 691792, PPID: 691184.
            Name: C, PID: 696268, PPID: 691792.
         Name: C, PID: 695220, PPID: 695896.
      Name: C, PID: 694204, PPID: 695816.
         Name: C, PID: 695496, PPID: 691184.
```

Here's the modified program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
void B();
void C();
void D();
void E();

void printIndent();

int indentLevel = 0;

int main (){
    int status;
    printIndent();
    printf("Name: %s, PID: %d, PPID: %d.\n", "A", getpid(), getppid());
    fflush(stdout);
    if (fork() == 0) {
       ++indentLevel;
       B();
    }

    if (fork() == 0) {
       ++indentLevel;
        C();
    }
    wait(&status);  
}

void B(){
    //B process
    int status;
    printIndent();
    printf("Name: %s, PID: %d, PPID: %d.\n", "B", getpid(), getppid());
    fflush(stdout);
    if (fork() == 0) {
       ++indentLevel;
        E();
    }
    if (fork() == 0) {
       ++indentLevel;
        D();
    }
    wait(&status);
}

void C(){
    //C process
    printIndent();
    printf("Name: %s, PID: %d, PPID: %d.\n", "C", getpid(), getppid());
    fflush(stdout);
}

void E(){
    //E process
    printIndent();
    printf("Name: %s, PID: %d, PPID: %d.\n", "E", getpid(), getppid());
    fflush(stdout);
}

void D(){
    //D process
    printIndent();
    printf("Name: %s, PID: %d, PPID: %d.\n", "D", getpid(), getppid());
    fflush(stdout);
}

void printIndent()
{
   int i = 0;
   for ( ; i < indentLevel; ++i )
   {
      printf("   ");
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. but I can't understand why D and C runs multiple times?

Comment: After process `A` forks to create process `B`, it continues to run still and calls `C()`. Process `B` calls `B()` but after it returns from `B()`, it continues to execute the next statement, which results in `C()` getting called.